# How to set Width of UserControl with FallbackValue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls

I have created a very basic UserControl

```
<StackPanel Margin="0,0,10,0" Width="{Binding ElementName=CurrentPresenter, Path=ActualWidth}" Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding HeaderText, ElementName=thisUserControl}"/>
    <TextBlock Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ValueText, ElementName=thisUserControl}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I want it to have a width of "90" by default, but if another value is given it shall use it.

If I do it as in the code given above, there is no FallbackValue, so it uses the given Width or, if none is given, the minimal possible to diplay its content. Using it like:

```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <local:UserStackPanelList Height="60" HeaderText="Name" ValueText="{Binding Path=ShareName}" Width="200"/>
```

If I use the following instead for the UserControl

```
<StackPanel Margin="0,0,10,0" Width="{Binding ElementName=CurrentPresenter, Path=ActualWidth, FallbackValue=90}" Orientation="Vertical">
```

The item itself uses the given width (200), but the TextBlocks stay at a width of 90.

I have tried to give the UserControl a **Name="thisUserControl"** so I can use it as **ElementName**, but that doesent work either. The item stays at a width of 200 but the TextBlocks only take up 90 (FallbackValue of StackPanel) even if the text is longer to be displayed in full.

How can I achive that it works as desired?

Edit:
I have this: 
[image]

Which is a ListView with an ItemTemplate

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Shares}" Name="LV">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Background="{Binding Path=Backgropund}" Margin="5,2.5,5,2.5" >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <local:UserStackPanelList Height="60" HeaderText="Name" ValueText="{Binding Path=ShareName}" Width="200"/>
                                <local:UserStackPanelList Height="60" HeaderText="Amount" ValueText="{Binding Path=Amount}"/>
```

Which looks pretty nice (to me). However, if the ShareName is long, it gets cut to the FallbackValue of Width (90). I looked into ListView.View -> GridView but it does not look half as nice. I could not get the Binding to the BackgroundColor to work as well. But having the header instead of defining it for each item is pretty nice. So if you could suggest a better Layout I would be happy to hear. Some code would be pretty nice as well. I couldd not get the hang of https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listview-overview "Styling a ListView That Implements a GridView" chapter...

Cheers Thoms

Comment: You shouldn't bind Width and/or Height at all. Use proper layout by appropriate Panels instead, e.g. Grid or DockPanel. If you would explain the desired behavior we might be able to provide a reasonable solution.

Comment: Why not bind it to the TextBlocks? The stack will accommodate to fit them

Comment: @Clemens: I edited my post. Hope you can help out.